# Resurface uneven stone fireplace

Tags: fireplace, remodeling, stone

We owned this house for about 3.5 years and really interested in refacing this fireplace. Curious, can this be done? What are my options?

The stone sticks out at different angles and depths, our next challenge is a slanted ceiling. These two scenarios make it really difficult to figure this one out. Any advice, see pics. Thanks in advance!

[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Which way is up for these pictures?

Comment: What is behind the stone veneer?

Comment: Could you please submit a picture of the whole wall with the firebox and perhaps another at the opening of the firebox showing how the stone meets it?

Comment: All, sorry for the poor photos. I uploaded some new ones in my original post. Hoping these are a bit better. Please excuse the mess, I'm in the middle of remodeling my bathroom and dust is everywhere with all this drywall work!

Comment: Is it natural or "cultured" stone? How thick?

Comment: I believe it is a natural stone, the thickness varies as some are much thicker than others. I can't get a good measurement on it since I don't have any sitting freely. They're larger though, feel very corse and heavy. Sorry this isn't an area of expertise for me (masonary), so a bit vague on the details of the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Can this be resurfaced, Yes.  You have several options but first we would need to know what kind of finish you desire. If it is a smooth surface removing the stone is not really that hard but very messy. I use an air chizzle with a wide blade to pop the stone off. In some cases there is brick behind the stone in others just the wall. I have done both in the past. Once the stone is down it can be sheetrocked or a different surface like tile. The last couple I did were large like this and both were removed and sheetrocked making a smaller area and mantle just around the fireplace the look was more modern than the 60's era wall. One in my home I put up cement board over the brick with a concave shape floor to ceiling ~8´ wide and used terracotta square tiles cutting the stone /tile area to 1/3 the original width I thought this looked , still looks nice, so it comes down to what do you want. The sheetrock remodels were less difficult on the brick I installed furring strips to attach the sheetrock the area connecting to the fire box I used large 18" slate slabs around the opening, on the other was porcilin that the owner ordered both looked quite nice 1 with collums to support the mantle made of wood the other mantle was supported by the brick work behind the wall.so it can be done, but it is a messy job to remove I would recommend getting a large painters tarp to put down to protect the flooring and in the area you are working I put down a sheet of plywood for the stones that pop off that you don't catch hit the plywood and further prevent damage to the flooring during the demo work.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response, it's nice to know I have options, unfortunately this will most likely cause me to refinish the tile around the base and ceiling around the top of the fireplace. At least now I know it can be done, thank you so much! This is on the list of "things to do when I have more free time" :)